# Internet checksum -- Adding hex numbers together for checksum

Tags: python, networking, hex

I came across the following example of creating an Internet Checksum:

> Take the example IP header `45 00 00 54 41 e0 40 00 40 01 00 00 0a 00 00 04 0a 00 00 05`:
>
> 1. Adding the fields together yields the two’s complement sum `01 1b 3e`.
> 2. Then, to convert it to one’s complement, the carry-over bits are added to the first 16-bits: `1b 3e + 01 = 1b 3f`.
> 3. Finally, the one’s complement of the sum is taken, resulting to the checksum value `e4c0`.

I was wondering how the IP header is added together to get `01 1b 3e`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split your IP header into 16-bit parts.

```
45 00 
00 54 
41 e0 
40 00 
40 01 
00 00 
0a 00 
00 04 
0a 00 
00 05
```

The sum is `01 1b 3e`. You might want to look at how packet header checksums are being calculated here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4_header_checksum.

Answer (score 1):

The IP header is added together with carry in hexadecimal numbers of 4 digits.
i.e. the first 3 numbers that are added are 0x4500 + 0x0054 + 0x41e0 +...